# How to validate a string with these requirement

Tags: kotlin

These are requirement, I finish the 1 and 3, how can I apply the second to my check? And is my code for 1 and 3 correct?

1. start with the alphabet
2. it can only include under-score, no others.
3. its length is between 3~10

```
if(id[0].isLetter() || (id.length in 3..10))
```

example: abc_def
if this string has another stuff, like adc/def, it's wrong

Comment: Can you provide some examples?
Also, I dont fully understand rule 1. Maby the examples will clear my doubt

Comment: @Damian added the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match those requirements.

Im no regex expert but using this [tool](https://regexr.com/) I came up with this one:

`([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z_]){2,9}`

Then you should add the regex assert in your code, like this:

```kotlin
val examples = listOf("good", "also_good", "_not_good", "b4d", "iok", "this_is_too_long_to_pass", "a")

examples.forEach { example ->
    if(example.matches(Regex("([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z_]){2,9}"))) {
        println("'$example' is ok")
    } else {
         println("'$example' is NOT ok")
    }
}
```

Regex explanation:

**[a-zA-Z]{1}** = exactly 1 letter

**[a-zA-Z_0-9]){2,9}** = betweeen 2 and 9 letters or numbers or underscore

Comment: Hi, in this one "b4b" is not ok? I would like number is ok

Comment: Then you should add numbers to the second term:

`([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z_0-9]){2,9}`

Whith this one "b4d" will match but not "4nything"

Comment: One more question, what does {1} means?

Comment: {1} means "Exactly one".

Translated the regex would be something like:

[a-zA-Z]{1} Exactly 1 letter;
[a-zA-Z_0-9]){2,9} Betweeen 2 and 9 letters or numbers or underscore

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` function to iterate each character and return true if each and every character satisfies the condition.

```
fun validate(input: String): Boolean {
    return input.length in 3..10 && input.all { it.isLetter() || it == '_' }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, it.isLetter() is checking the whole string is letter or not, what if I only need the first char be letter?

Comment: It's checking your whole string because the lambda passed to `all` is called on each character in the String and only returns true if the lambda results in `true` for every character in the String. Your own code in the question checks only the first character for being a letter, but if you do it that way you'll want to check the length first, because an input of length zero will cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException crash if you use `[0]` on it.